# UPDATE with INNER JOIN on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, inner-join

I have 2 tables `Users` and `Orders`. Primary key of `Users` is `UserId`, which I have defined as foreign key in the `Orders` table. I have added a new column of `UserName` to `Orders`. I want to import `UserName` from `Users` table.

I'm trying to run this code, but it keeps giving me errors. Can someone tell me what could be wrong?

```
UPDATE Orders 
SET Orders.UserName = Users.UserName 
INNER JOIN Users ON Orders.UserId = Users.UserId;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not the right syntax

```
UPDATE O 
SET O.UserName = U.UserName 
from Orders O
INNER JOIN Users U ON O.UserId = U.UserId ;
```

You need to start using `Alias` for tables references when there is more than one table involved in your query. Using Alias names makes the query more readable.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing orders table name

```
UPDATE Orders 
SET Orders.UserName = Users.UserName 
from Orders
INNER JOIN Users ON Orders.UserId = Users.UserId ;
```

Answer (score 1):

No `UPDATE` with `INNER JOIN`, please re-write your query as follow:

You can use `INNER JOIN` only after `FROM` clause

```
UPDATE Orders SET Orders.UserName = Users.UserName 
FROM Users WHERE Orders.UserId = Users.UserId
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually like the CTE version of the update here, because it lets us expression the join logic as we would in a select, without any potential confusion:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT o.UserName AS user_old, u.UserName AS user_new
    FROM Orders o
    INNER JOIN Users u ON u.UserId = o.UserId
)

UPDATE cte
SET user_old = user_new;
```

Comment: @wakanada My answer becomes useful in cases where it's easier to just write a select.  In this case, the answer your accepted is not too verbose, but sometimes an update can be.

Answer (score 0):

Your query structure should be like below :

```
UPDATE 

t1
SET 
    t1.c1 = t2.c2,
    t2.c2 = expression,
    ...   
FROM 
    t1
    [INNER | LEFT] JOIN t2 ON join_predicate
WHERE 
    where_predicate;
```

So your actual query should be like below :

```
UPDATE Orders SET Orders.UserName = Users.UserName 
FROM Users WHERE Orders.UserId = Users.UserId
```